# Can Microsoft's Azure DocumentDB be used as a backend for Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, azure-cosmosdb

Today I read about how DocDb now supports MongoDB api's. Does that mean we will be able to use it as the backend for a Meteor project?

I know from seeing some of the user list traffic that getting Meteor to accept any other database than MongoDB is quite problematic. However, now that there is another vendor selling the same api, perhaps we can get some competition into the mix?

http://techcrunch.com/2016/03/31/microsofts-documentdb-now-lets-you-use-your-mad-mongodb-skills/

Comment: "Can DocumentDB be used as a backend for <insert framework name here>" isn't a programming question and is off-topic for StackOverflow. The announcement is framework-agnostic. The only way to answer your question is for you to try it out.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, my question isn't about DocDb but about Meteor, I reworded.

Comment: I'm started to get frustrated with how many questions in this community are flagged. This question was flagged as too broad indicating that it would "take a book to answer" it. However, it's not too broad to be "answered in a few paragraphs" (the criteria given by SO) as evidenced by the fact that my answer was accepted by the asker. SO is about helping folks. Sure, to preserve the community there needs to be some standard. I just think that there are few members of the community that often go beyond what is necessary for the good of the community.

Comment: Imho, the whole point of SO is with the huge scale effect, to find the few people who find certain questions 'easy' and have them answer it. Unless the question is truly too general and has lots of answers, I do not think it is fair to vote down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are asking because DocumentDB just came out with MongoDB driver-level protocol support. However, I don't think that's enough to use DocumentDB for Meteor Apps, at least not in production. The main reason why not has to do with the way Meteor uses MongoDB's oplog tailing. A Meteor application installs itself as another "secondary", that way, changes that are written to the primary are automatically sent to the Meteor app which then decides what end users need what updates and sends them using the real-time transport mechanism built into Meteor. It's very efficient and results in getting real-time user behavior for free.

Since that particular interface of MongoDB's is undocumented and essentially unsupported, DocumentDB does not implement it.

That said, there is a fall-back mode for Meteor that does not use oplog tailing. It's not considered appropriate for production, but it just might work with you plugging DocumentDB in on the back end using MongoDB driver support. It all depends upon whether or not DocumentDB implements all of the MongoDB protocol features used by this Meteor fall-back mode.

Also, there are several other experiments to plug in different back ends to Meteor. I think all of require low-level modifications to Meteor itself (as opposed to just a plugin) and I don't know of any that are used in production. And, if you got it to work, without some eventing system (like MongoDB's oplog tailing), it would never be performant.

Comment: Another answer! It looks like this might be full-fledged available in the relatively near future. Already a subset of commands are working for someone with a former Parse mobile Backend as a service. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-publication-of-parse-server-with-azure-managed-services/  "Adrian Hall [adrianha@MSFT]  DocDB is rolling out a Mongo shim for support of this project. It isn't available generally yet and supports a subset of Mongo."

Comment: Cool. Do you know if it installs itself as a secondary in DocDB? or use some eventing api that isn't public yet? I've been hoping for an eventing api for DocDB. That said, I have transitioned all of the projects I was developing with Meteor over to React on the front-end with Firebase/ReactFire on the back end. It's all of the goodness of Meteor (latency comp, real-time UI, etc.) without waiting on Meteor React to become production ready.

Comment: They seem to be very scant on tech details, however, they have a phone call; The #MSFT database teams will be hosting a special Ask Me Anything session on /r/Azure on April 8th 10am-1pm PDT: http://msft.it/6018BiYtY . Good to know re your React/Fire choices. I have been observing mainly so far, lots of practice MongoDb's.